# Unable to add layouts to an activity using Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout

Using Android Studio, in my activity's .xml I can't edit the layout in regards to which layout type the overall one is. The only way for me to change layouts is to copy-paste the layout code from somewhere on the internet and I've been doing it like that for the past month.
This is ridiculous. Why am I having this issue?
Drag and dropping a layout on to the activity inside of the designer does nothing.

Upon creating an empty activity of which the default layout is "ConstraintLayout", I can't do anything with that layout inside of the designer. I can only remove it by deleting the code from within the .xml view.

My build.gradle (Module: app):

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "hr.package.name.testsigninna"
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:17.0.0'
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
}
```

The problem is present in all projects I make.

Comment: please put here your Gradle file or screenshot from your XML file

Comment: add below code and try again:
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'

Comment: change constraint layout to linea layout or relative layout

Comment: I have tried adding the support.design:28.0.0 dependency, it did nothing.

Changing a layout is what's problematic for me. The initial layout, the one containing everything in a given layout, cannot be change by drag and dropping a layout while inside of designerView, but can only be changed by directly editing the XML text.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but please check the gradle or it's version may be too old whether all the dependencies are working or not. Sync them and rebuild the project.

Comment: I have done that, I do it after every dependency I add to the project. It doesn't fix the problem.